# Jquery Datepicker only allow 3 weeks date range selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

We have a jQuery Datepcker on our hotel website and we only want to allow guest to select no more than 3 weeks on our booking form. I have tried to find a solution on this forum and the web, but didn't come across an answer that would work. Below is the code we have now. I tried using the maxDate: '+3W' however that would disable all the days except 3 weeks from the current date. Whatever the guest selects for the arrival date the departure date should only allow max of 3 weeks. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $( ".datepicker[name='A']" ).datepicker({
  showOn: 'both',
  defaultDate: "+1d",
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
  minDate: "+1D",      
  changeMonth: false,
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( ".datepicker[name='D']" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( ".datepicker[name='D']" ).datepicker({
  showOn: 'both',
  defaultDate: "+2d",      
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',        
  changeMonth: false,
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( ".datepicker[name='A']" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
```

Comment: So I have tried the maxdate: '+21d', but that only limits21 days from today. I want to limit 21 days from the arrival date. I also tried the startDate: new Date(), but that broke it. Someone is sitting on my answer..

Comment: Finally figured it out myself. This is an easy way of doing it. Most articles were just too extensive to do something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

```
    $( ".datepicker[name='A']" ).datepicker({
  showOn: 'both',
  defaultDate: "+1d",
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
  minDate: "+2D",      
  changeMonth: false,
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    console.log(new Date(new Date(selectedDate).getTime() + 1814400000));
    $( ".datepicker[name='D']" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    $( ".datepicker[name='D']" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date(new Date(selectedDate).getTime() + 1814400000) );
  }
});
$( ".datepicker[name='D']" ).datepicker({
  showOn: 'both',
  defaultDate: "+2d",      
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',        
  changeMonth: false,
  buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( ".datepicker[name='A']" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
```

If you have a better way then please post it up.